# Store with json reader is not working

Tags: c#, parsing, extjs4

I have following json created after I sereliaze a dictionary

```
{"Results":["{\"BaseCurrency\":\"USD\",\"TermCurrency\":\"JPY\"}","{\"BaseCurrency\":\"USD\",\"TermCurrency\":\"JPY\"}","{\"BaseCurrency\":\"USD\",\"TermCurrency\":\"JPY\"}","{\"BaseCurrency\":\"USD\",\"TermCurrency\":\"JPY\"}"],"Total":4}
```

When I try to load it into the extjs store , the store is not loaded

```
var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    fields: fields,
    pageSize: itemsPerPage,
    proxy: {
    type: 'ajax',
    url: getDataWithPageURL,
    reader: {
    type: 'json',
    root: 'Results',
    totalProperty: 'Total'
            }
    }
});
```

But if I remove slash hard coded and it's working

```
{"Results":["{"BaseCurrency":"USD","TermCurrency":"JPY"}","{"BaseCurrency":"USD","TermCurrency":"JPY"}","{"BaseCurrency":"USD","TermCurrency":"JPY"}","{"BaseCurrency":"USD"}"],"Total":4}
```

I create json using **Newtonsoft.Json**

```
Dictionary<string, object> dict = new Dictionary<string, object>();

            string s = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dist);
```

How can I remove slash in server side in order to produce valid json for extjs store.

I tried

```
result = result.Replace("\"","'");
```

And

```
result =result.Replace("\"", @"""")
```

It's not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clearly, Ext doesn't like that you have encoded a json object as a string and then put them in another json object.  You have two options that I see.

1. See if you can return the dict on the server-side without first converting it into a string.  Some code, somewhere, is taking your string and putting it in a json object with 'Results' and 'Total'.  Check to see if that code can take a `Dictionary` as-is.
2. Unwrap the 'Results' propery on the client-side.  One way would be to make your own reader:

```
Ext.define('MyReader', {
  extend: 'Ext.data.reader.Json',
  alias: 'reader.my-json',
  read: function(object) {
    object.Results = Ext.Array.map(object.Results, Ext.decode);
    return this.callParent([object]);
  }
});
```

Then use `type: 'my-json'` in your reader config.

Here is my test case:

```
var data = {"Results":["{\"BaseCurrency\":\"USD\",\"TermCurrency\":\"JPY\"}","{\"BaseCurrency\":\"USD\",\"TermCurrency\":\"JPY\"}","{\"BaseCurrency\":\"USD\",\"TermCurrency\":\"JPY\"}","{\"BaseCurrency\":\"USD\",\"TermCurrency\":\"JPY\"}"],"Total":4};

Ext.define('Currency', {
  extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
  fields: [
    { name: 'BaseCurrency', type: 'string' },
    { name: 'TermCurrency', type: 'string' }
  ]
});

Ext.define('MyReader', {
  extend: 'Ext.data.reader.Json',
  alias: 'reader.my-json',
  read: function(object) {
    object.Results = Ext.Array.map(object.Results, Ext.decode);
    return this.callParent([object]);
  }
});

var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
  model: 'Currency',
  data: data,
  proxy: {
    type: 'memory',
    reader: {
      type: 'my-json',
      root: 'Results',
      totalProperty: 'Total'
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Great answer ! Thanks ! I like option number 2. Do you have working example ?

Comment: I put the code but I receive an error that "I missing class MYReader or one of the dependecies"

Comment: Oops.  `Ext.create` should have been `Ext.define`.  I'll fix the answer.

Comment: I enable congif by   Ext.Loader.setConfig({ enabled: true }); and put after you code but now I have other error "Cannot create instance of unrecognized alias reader.my-json"

Comment: Hmm.  Perhaps the alias idea was bad.  Try creating the reader directly: `reader: Ext.create('MyReader', {root: 'Results', totalProperty: 'Total'})` in your Store definition.

Comment: Now I managed to create MyReader but I receive "records is null"

Comment: I posted new question based on your advice. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8438243/create-custom-json-reader Thanks for the help

Comment: Ok I think I got it.  I had several bugs in the code, alias should have been `reader.my-json`, the results needed to be `map`ped since it was an array, the result of `read` was not being returned.  Try it now.

Comment: I cannot use it as a model because json dynamic and I know only in runtime. If store is not based on model what I supposed to return ?