# Create custom json reader

Tags: extjs4

I created custom json reader as suggest by James Clark in [following post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8437212/store-with-json-reader-is-not-working)

Here is a code for creating custom json

```
  Ext.define('MyReader', {
            extend: 'Ext.data.reader.Json',
            alias: 'my-json',
            read: function (object) {
                debugger;
                object.Results = Ext.decode(object.responseText);
                this.callParent([object]);
            }
        });
```

In store definition I assing custom reader

```
var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
//model: 'Option',
    fields: fields,
    pageSize: itemsPerPage,
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: getDataWithPageURL,
        **reader:Ext.create('MyReader', {root: 'Results', totalProperty: 'Total'})**
    }
});
```

The json that I receiving from clients look like this

```
{"Results":["{\"BaseCurrency\":\"USD\",\"TermCurrency\":\"JPY\"}","{\"BaseCurrency\":\"USD\",\"TermCurrency\":\"JPY\"}","{\"BaseCurrency\":\"USD\",\"TermCurrency\":\"JPY\"}","{\"BaseCurrency\":\"USD\",\"TermCurrency\":\"JPY\"}"],"Total":4}
```

I receiving an error in ext-js.js
I debuged it and the error occurs in Ext.data.proxy.Server class in 
following code

```
if (success === true) {
        reader = me.getReader();
        result = reader.read(me.extractResponseData(response));
        records = result.records;
```

**result is undefined.**

Please help

Comment: See the edits to my answer in the original question.  There were some bugs in my initial code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problems with the code in my initial attempt were:

1. the read() method should return a value, so it should say:

```
return this.callParent([object]);
```

1. The alias should have been `'reader.my-json'`
2. The results needed to be mapped because it was an array:

```
object.Results = Ext.Array.map(object.Results, Ext.decode);
```

With those fixed, the store can use the simpler reader definition:

```
reader: {
  type: 'my-json',
  root: 'Results',
  totalProperty: 'Total'
}
```

But see the complete test case in the original question for the full code.  I apologize for not having thoroughly tested the code I initially proposed.

Comment: I cannot use model . The code is not working I am failing on map function

Comment: read: function (object) {
                debugger;
                //object.Results = Ext.decode(object.responseText);
                object.Results = Ext.Array.map(object.Results, Ext.decode);
                return this.callParent([object]);
                
                //return object.Results;
            }

Comment: Sorry, no.  Perhaps you want to post your question to StackOverflow?